# Python: How to include a var into a string(win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation)

Tags: python-3.x, winapi

I'm coding a simple software to change pc Timezone via python
The problem that appears it's sound very easy but in the end didn't find any methods to work

I just trying to include a var timezone instead of Pacific Standard Time

Part of code with issue:

```
timezone = "Eastern Standard Time"

win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation((-600,u'Pacific Standard Time',(2000,4,1,3,0,0,0,0),0,u'Pacific Standard Time',(2000,10,1,2,0,0,0,0),-60))
```

I've tried:
%s
format()

It seems to me that all issue is because of '' inside were var should be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try replacing `"Pacific Standard Time"` with simply `timezone`

Comment: great man, thank you. So easy, I just complicate myself too hard with %s and format()